# Solve the following eigen equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics

I tried to solve the following [eigen equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of (1-1) on the way to one problem on the [quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544842/the-eigenstates-basis-states-and-the-ground-state-on-two-state-quantum-system)
, but the eigenvector seems to have an imaginary part (see 1-10) despite using the [hermitian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix). Is my answer correct?

> **【My question】**
>   Solve the following eigen equation.
>   $$\left(\begin{matrix}\varepsilon_1&\bar{\gamma}\\\gamma&\varepsilon_2\\\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right)=\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right)\tag{1-1}$$
>   Here, ${\varepsilon_1}$ and ${\varepsilon_2}$ are real number,  $\gamma$ is a complex number, and $\bar{\gamma}$ is a conjugate complex number of the $\gamma$, these are regarded as the constant value.

**【My answer】**
**(1)Eigenvalues** 
$$\left|\begin{matrix}\varepsilon_1-\lambda&\bar{\gamma}\\\gamma&\varepsilon_2-\lambda\\\end{matrix}\right|=0\tag{1-2}$$

therefore,
$$\left(\lambda\ -\varepsilon_1\right)\left(\lambda-\varepsilon_2\right)-\left|\gamma\right|^2\ =\ 0 \tag{1-3}$$
$${\lambda\ }^2-\left(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2\right)\lambda+\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2-\left|\gamma\right|^2\ \ =0\tag{1-4}$$

Using the [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) we get,
　
$${E_+}=\frac{\left({\varepsilon_1}+{\varepsilon_2}\right)\ +\sqrt{\left(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2\right)^2\ +\ 4\left(\left|\gamma\right|^2-\ \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\right)}}{2}\ =\frac{\left(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2\right)\ }{2}\ +\ \frac{D\ }{2}\tag{1-5}$$
and
$${E_-}=\frac{\left({\varepsilon_1}+{\varepsilon_2}\right)\ -\sqrt{\left(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2\right)^2\ +\ 4\left(\left|\gamma\right|^2-\ \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\right)}}{2}\ = \frac{\left(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2\right)\ }{2}\ - \ \frac{D\ }{2} .\tag{1-6}$$

Here,
$$D:= \sqrt{\left(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2\right)^2\ +\ 4\left(\left|\gamma\right|^2-\ \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\right)} .\tag{1-7}$$

**(2)Eigenvectors** 
Consider the 1 st row of the (1-1)
$$\ \ x\varepsilon_1\ +\bar{\gamma}y=\lambda x\ \tag{1-8}$$
therefore,
$$y=\frac{x\gamma}{\left|\gamma\right|^2}\left(\lambda-{\varepsilon_1}\right)
=-\ \frac{x\gamma}{2\left|\gamma\right|^2}\left(\left(\varepsilon_1\ -\ {\varepsilon_2}\right)\pm\ D\right)\tag{1-9}$$
therefore, the eigen vectors are
$$\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-\ \frac{\gamma}{2\left|\gamma\right|^2}\left(\left(\varepsilon_1\ -\ \varepsilon_2\right)\pm\ D\right)\\\end{matrix}\right)\tag{1-10}$$

Comment: The fact that a matrix is hermitian implies that its *eigenvalues* are real, but the *eigenvectors* can have non-real coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.